# Authenticated login for google enterprise account users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, google-oauth, google-openid

Setting up an internal application for my company. We would like users to use their company gmail accounts to login (we have an enterprise account) so we can manage their access and remove access where necessary. This will also prevent anyone else being able to access the application.

I've looked in to SSO but am unsure whether this is the right path for what we are trying to achieve. I've also looked into oauth but as we already manage the accounts for the users, it seems counterintuitive to ask them for permission to access their data which we already own and manage.

If we do go with SSO, the only guide I can find uses Auth0 as a third party identity provider... again, this seems counterintuitive when all the information is already on our google account.... there is an option to use Google as the IDP but not much information on how to implement this.

Comment: I am not really sure i understand your question but if your just trying to let users login via their google accounts then you should be looking at google signin or google open id.    Oauth2 is just for granting access to data though the apis which it doesn't sound like you are trying to do.

Comment: @DaImTo -Thank you very much for the info. I hadn't even seen the option for google sign-in. I think you are correct that this will be the best way forward. 

The reason we are implementing something like this is that we have an enterprise G-Suite account for all of the staff... so each staff member has their own company email through the g-suite system. The idea was to restrict access to the system for just our staff which would give us the ability to easily remove access through g-suite if a staff member left the company.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is something along the lines of [google signin](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in)  Signin is all about authentication all it does is authenticate (login in)  a user.

Using this should give you the ability to log in your gsuite users there should be nothing about granting permissions to access data as this is not Oauth2.  Its just a login.

You can get information about who the user is though

```
function onSignIn(googleUser) {
  var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
  console.log('ID: ' + profile.getId()); // Do not send to your backend! Use an ID token instead.
  console.log('Name: ' + profile.getName());
  console.log('Image URL: ' + profile.getImageUrl());
  console.log('Email: ' + profile.getEmail()); // This is null if the 'email' scope is not present.
}
```

Getting this to work with ruby might be tricky i am not sure i am not a ruby dev but i am sure its possible. I know i can get it working with .net core so i dont see why it wouldnt work with ruby.